# Solving the xinetd "Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: ubuntu, vnc-server, xinetd

I'm trying to get a simple websocket proxy to work with xinetd.

The proxy is here : https://github.com/kumina/wsproxy
(basic proxy for vnc)

Here's my xinetd/wsproxy config:

```
service wsproxy
{

    type        = UNLISTED
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    user        = root
    wait        = no
    port        = 8080
    server      = /usr/sbin/wsproxy
    server_args = 5000 9999 
    disable     = no
    log_type    = SYSLOG daemon info
    flags       = NOLIBWRAP
}
```

Also tried various changes like 'wait=yes' and 'wait=no' still the same results

i get a hundred entries like this one in syslog :

```
ubuntu xinetd[3707]: warning: can't get client address:...
...Transport endpoint is not connected
```

and finally :

```
xinetd[8283]: Deactivating service wsproxy due to excessive incoming connections.
```

xinetd is running and in netstat as well.

Pulling my hairs out, can't find why it doesn't run.

(running ubuntu 11.04 x64)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the vncserver in the backend is up and running?
Even if wsproxy itself is running (check with telnet localhost 8080), if the vncserver isn't running, you might be running into this problem.

Checked with Debian Squeeze (i386) and Scientific Linux (x86_64) that your xinetd-config is correct. Works like charm.

Comment: Yes it's up and running; i can smoothly connect directly using a vnc client.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration ?

Comment: Sorry, my answer earlier was misleading. I only checked that the xinetd-config is correct and doesn't throw any errors at me. However, since I was curious I tried to get noVNC with wsproxy running with no result at all. I found the documentation quite sparse. I got wsproxy running, installed noVNC but whatever I try to connect to, I didn't succeed. Sorry for the misleading answer. But I'm interested too: in case you get it running, let me now. Please unvote for my answer.

Comment: I got one idea left though: From all the documentation I've read, you must make sure that the hostname is known to all machines in the chain. Your client and the machine running wsproxy. So if you don't have an entry in your /etc/hosts on the wsproxy-machine, add it.

Comment: Ok, turns out it's a bug noVNC side; it doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox but only with Safari. See this issue : https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/issues/89

Thank you again, it's always good to have 2nd eye on the thing.